# Can Slick query be plain SQL?

Tags: playframework-2.0, slick

Is it possible to use plain SQL queries in Slick 2.0? I found in documentation it is true for 1.0. I'm wondering it it is true for the new one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible, [syntax depends on your slick version](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.2/sql.html), check also [this example](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/src/sphinx/code/PlainSQL.scala):

```
val q2 = Q.query[Double, (String, String)]("""
  select c.name, s.name
  from coffees c, suppliers s
  where c.price < ? and s.id = c.sup_id
""")
```